# Is there any way to show user data in Log4j logging message?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, customization

I know, question looks bit confusing. Let me explain it in detail.

I have some data which I want to show everytime in `Logger` along with user message.

Ex. 
`log4j.appender.filer.layout.ConversionPattern=`**`%-5p %d{yyyyddMM-HH:mm:ss} %m%n`**
**Console:** WARN 20162208-18:34:35 Test info

This is the patter I've set in Log4j.properties file which works absolutely fine.

Now problem arises when I want to add some user data in this pattern. This user data will be some value which will be fetched from user input. After the user data, the console should look some thing like this:
**Console:** WARN User_data 20162208-18:34:35 Test info

So my question is, Can we set/send user data in logger pattern?

I have seen some examples where user was extending `Appender` class and overriding `append()` method. But I am looking for some different approach.

Comment: Do you want that *user data* in every single log ?

Comment: @TAsk Yes! That's right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically place contextual data in your logger entry, make use of the [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) feature in Log4j.

Here's an example:

```
// JAVA CODE
org.apache.log4j.MDC.put("User_data", "this is my user data");

// Log4j Pattern
%X{User_data}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!! But it wont be possible to keep the data in environment variables as data is fetched from user input which user will provide at run time..

Comment: I modified my answer for showing dynamic data in the logger entry.